# Express route with dynamic arguments in the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

first of all i am a very beginner of Node so my question gonna be surely basic. So, i learn Node with a website and i am blocked on a one Express exercice. I need to create a route that accepts dynamic arguments in the URL path and responds with quote (object see after in code) from the proper author.
The js is like follows :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var quotes = {
  'einstein': 'Life is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance you must keep moving',
  'berners-lee': 'The Web does not just connect machines, it connects people',
  'crockford': 'The good thing about reinventing the wheel is that you can get a round one',
  'hofstadter': 'Which statement seems more true: (1) I have a brain. (2) I am a brain.'
};

app.get('/quotes/:name', function(request, response){
  response.send(request.params.name); /*And i'm blocked here*/
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Sorry, you're going to need to give me a bit more than that. What exactly is the issue, and what do you mean by you're blocked there?

Comment: the issue is that apparently i dont send the quoute in my response.send function

Comment: Well, that makes sense. You're just sending the value of the parameter `:name` in the response...

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Node, it's basic JavaScript. `quotes[request.params.name]`.

Comment: Yes Ben i've tried that too quotes[request.params.name] and quotes.request.params.name even quotes["request.params.name"] but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the line you're blocked at:

```
response.send(quotes[request.params.name]);
```

This is conditional on the `:name` being right though, so you may want to check it exists in your `quotes` object with `Object.hasOwnProperty()` first.

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, perhaps problem with browser i gonna try to restart exercise, who knows ;]

Comment: This is literally the code I put into my `app.js` and ran it, and it works fine for me.

Comment: seems it was browser, just last question, now they ask me to close the response and response.send(quotes[request.params.name]).end(); doesn't seems to please them -_-

Comment: Try doing `response.end()` on a separate line.

Comment: OK I found out (not really used a hint but who cares) it was response.end(quote)... Thanks southrop !

Comment: it seems that i don't understand english ^^. Question is "Now, use the name parameter from the URL to retrieve a quote from the quotes object and write it out to the response. Note: No piping here, just write the quote string to the response like you did in previous levels (and then close the response)." I've tried everything i learned so far response.write(quotes[request.params.name]); response.end(quotes[request.params.name]); or request.on('end', function(){
   response.end(quotes[request.params.name]);
  }); and i have "Don't forget to write the quote out and then close the response."

Comment: Don't worry, I'm quite confused by that too. Have you tried good old `response.send(quotes[request.params.name])`?

Comment: In hint they say "Call the end() method, of the response object, and pass in the correct element in the quotes array. For example:

res.end(quote);"
So i try app.get('/quotes/:name', function(res, req){
  res.end(quotes[req.params.name]);
}); ... and nothing same Incorrect submission

Comment: ****** mother of god ! it was (request, response) ! not (response, request) >< !